# GitLab Pipeline: perform job except user (Runner machine)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to run specific job only / except push comes from specific user?

I could do it by script searching for the commit author at the beginning of every job, but maybe there is more elegant way.

---

**Explanation**

We use git lab Runner to merge develop to all other branches when develop is changed.

Our gitlab Runner has its own user with writes to push so it works like a charm.

The one thing we want to avoid is running specific resources-consuming jobs for branches pushed by that user (runner).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[skip ci]` string in the runners commit message for the merge. This wil skip the ci pipeline for that push. [Docs here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#skipping-jobs).

I use this when Gitlab runner pushes a tag.

Comment: oh, great! I didn't now that. But still - I wish to run tests, but not other jobs. It would be nice to have [skip <job_name>]